# Python program crashes on library import (Windows)

Tags: python, import, crash, pymysql

I have a Python program that needs pymysql library, but when I open the .py file it immediatly crashes when trying to execute

```
import pymysql
```

I cannot read any error message as the windows closes too quickly, the weird thing is that when I run the code in Pycharm it works perfectly fine!
Any idea on how to solve this issue?

--EDIT--

I have run the program via Command Prompt, and now it imports the module fine but gives me the error "Failed to load image from file". Again, when i run it on Pycharm it works perfectly fine. This is the complete code:

```
import pymysql
import wx
import wx.grid
import os
import sys

image_name = 'logo.bmp'
if getattr(sys, 'frozen', False):
    application_path = os.path.dirname(sys.executable)
elif __file__:
    application_path = os.path.dirname(__file__)
image_path = str(application_path) + '/' + image_name

class mainWindow(wx.Frame):

def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    wx.Frame.__init__(self, size=(380, 210), title='Venetex Database Manager',
                      style=wx.MINIMIZE_BOX | wx.CLOSE_BOX | wx.CAPTION,
                      *args, **kwargs)
    self.Centre()
    self.mainGUI()
    self.Show(True)
    self.Bind(wx.EVT_CLOSE, self.OnCloseFrame)

def mainGUI(self):
    panel = wx.Panel(self)

    image = wx.Bitmap(image_path)
    wx.StaticBitmap(panel, -1, image, (10, 10), (image.GetWidth(), image.GetHeight()))

    visualizza_button = wx.Button(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label='Visualizza Dati',
                                  pos=(200, 10 + 40))
    visualizza_button.SetSize((150, 25))
    modifica_button = wx.Button(panel, id=wx.ID_ANY, label='Modifica/Inserisci Dati',
                                pos=(200, 10 + image.GetHeight() - 65))
    modifica_button.SetSize((150, 25))

    visualizza_button.Bind(wx.EVT_BUTTON, self.visualizza)

def OnCloseFrame(self, event):
    dialog = wx.MessageDialog(self, message="Sei sicuro di voler uscire?", caption="Conferma uscita",
                              style=wx.YES_NO,
                              pos=wx.DefaultPosition)
    dialog.Show(True)
    response = dialog.ShowModal()

    if response == wx.ID_YES:
        self.Destroy()
    else:
        event.StopPropagation()

def visualizza(self, event):
    pass


def main():
    app = wx.App()
    mainWindow(None)
    app.MainLoop()
main()
sys.exit()
```

Comment: Try running it from the command line. That should print the stack

Comment: I tried, and now the program works but it crashes at another command (and still it runs perfectly fine in Pycharm)

Comment: Please post the stack so we can try to help you

Comment: Here is the source code!